# #Include <stdio.h> problem (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include, include-path

I am trying to do a project in C but I have problems with the string `#include<stdio.h>`, I tried several tutorials but none of them worked, my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

     int age;
     printf ("Enter age:");
     scanf ("% d", age);
     printf ("age is% d", age);
     return 0;

}
```

The problems are 2:

#Include errors were encountered. Update includePath.

Unable to open source file error code "stdio.h".

For this project I have created a folder, in which there is a folder called .dist and my Main.c file

(I have attached an image to be clearer)

[image]

Could anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: There is an error in your code `scanf ("%d", &age)`; it needs an `&`.

Comment: Is that an error message from your compiler, or your editor?

Comment: You're missing some config files, namely `c_cpp_properties.json`, `launch.json` and `tasks.json`. I don't quite remember but I believe that if you install the Microsoft C/C++ extension these will be automatically added, read more in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp,

Answer (score 4):

The error showed in the first picture is due to the incorrect setting of the IntelliSenseMode of the editor. I bet that you have installed gcc compiler on your computer and you should also set "gcc" on the IntelliSenseMode of the editor which, by default, has a wrong value  that freakout when it reads "#include <stdio.h>".

Comment: This was my problem on a new M1 Pro. VScode set "clang" as my default compiler but was looking for "gcc" in properties.json. Simply changing the path from clang to gcc resolved the issue. TY!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for all the advice, I added the files `c_cpp_proprietes.json`, `launch.json`, `task.json` and I added the Microsoft C / C ++ extension, I also fixed the code, but the problem remains before, also because I don't know what code I have to put in the files that I added maybe?[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, go to your C/C++ extension configuration and change your compiler path to `gcc.exe`

Then change Intellisense mode to `windows-gcc-x64`

Attached a screenshot for better understanding.

[VS Code

[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

So there are 2 problems here:

1st: In the 7th and 8th line of code you have written "% d" which should be "%d" to define the integer data type.

2nd: Again in the 7th line of code you forgot to put "&" before the variable "age" which provides the address of the variable to put the entered value.
[For better understanding attaching image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgohy.png)